# Img in ionic cordova popover component does not show

Tags: html, image, cordova, ionic-framework, popover

I would like that when a user presses a button in the app, a popup opens. This popup shows several rounded filter options([pictures infront of an invisible checkbox](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/13/button-switches-with-checkboxes-and-css3-fanciness/) ) which are are changing when pressed. Something like this:

[image: Picture of filter options]

The problem is that somehow I am not able to see the img in the popover component in ionic cordova while the popover element works fine otherwise. Is it actually possible to do that in ionic?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="filter-buttons">
<div class="metal">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>test</label>
  <img src="heavy.jpg" alt="stuff" height="42" width="42"> 
</div>
```

I also tried it as background in css:

```
.metal{
    background-image: url("heavy3.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the image in `www/assets`  and add this code

```
background: url(../assets/heavy3.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Hi Franco, thanks for your quick response! Your suggestion solved the problem, thank you, may I ask why I couldn't simply have the img in the same folder?

Comment: It should have no problem if you put the image in the same folder as your .scss file in that way the url should be like you putted in first place. You should read this that explains very well the routes https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp